# Is an Index seek operation more costly compared to index scan when the data volume is high?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I understand that table scan looks at every record in a table. And a table seek looks at specific records.

Also, an Index scan/seek concept is same as above with the difference being that the values are in sorted order.

**Question**: Is an Index seek operation more costly compared to index scan when the data volume of the item being searched is high? and why?

Example: Lets say statistics are stale and the estimated rows is 100 but actual rows are 100000. The engine decides to use index seek. Will this more costly than index scan and why?

```
SELECT StockItemID 
FROM Examples.OrderLines 
WHERE StockItemID = 1;
```

I am referring to a book "Exam Ref 70-762 Developing SQL Databases" which has this example and it reads on page number 338 as: "Because this (stale statistics) value is relatively low, the query optimizer generated a plan using an index seek, which could be less optimal than performing a scan when data volumes are high". I am trying to understand why a seek is considered expensive.

Comment: This is better asked in DBA, but let me ask you this, what do you think would be faster for you to do? "Find Mr Albert Smith in the phone Book. The phone numbers are in a random order." or "Find Mr Albert Smith in the phone Book. All the Smiths are on Page 544 and are sorted alphabetically by first name." The former is a scan, the latter is a seek.

Comment: Please re-read the question. It is regarding an index seek vs scan, and an Index is ALWAYS in sorted order!

Comment: An index seek does not need to retrieve a single row; it can be used to seek to the lower end of a range, then scan the rest of the matching rows in order. This will show up as an index seek operator, but includes a range scan. In general, an index seek would only be more costly if it was executed many times, where a single scan would be more efficient. You can get this if joins are involved. If you need to know, for a particular query, if the choice of scan vs. seek was optimal or not, you can use an explicit query hint (combined with `SET STATISTICS IO`) to find out.

Comment: Both index seeks and scans return rows in sorted order. Which is more costly will depend on the number of rows and pages touched and other factors in the execution plan, especially for non-trivial queries. I would expect a seek in your example query to be most efficient if the `StockIdemID` column is indexed regardless of the estimated/actual rows. BTW, if the estimate is wrong, update stats, although it probably won't change the plan here.

Comment: Hi Dan - I am referring to a book "Exam Ref 70-762 Developing SQL Databases" which has the same example as my questions and it reads as: "Because this (stale statistics) value is relatively low, the query optimizer generated a plan using an index seek, which could be less optimal than performing a scan when data volumes are high". I am trying to understand why a seek is considered expensive.

Comment: Well, unless the book actually cites how they created the database, and what version of SQL Server was used (i.e. they make it reproducible), I'm inclined to call it wrong. This query should inspire a trivial plan, and provided an index exists on `StockItemId`, it will use an index seek with a range scan for it, simply because that is the best choice period. A scan could at most be just as good, and that only if all values in the index are identical.

Comment: I think that this example is very poor.  As Martin Smith points out, you will always get a seek for this query in practice (as long as there is an index on StockItemID), but, the point that the author of the book seems to be making is:  "If the query optimiser decided to do an index seek for each individual row, why would this be more expensive than simply scanning the leaf level of the index?"  To which the answer is that the seeks would have to read non-leaf level pages for each leaf-level read.  It's just confusing as it is not a real-world example.

Comment: *"and an Index is ALWAYS in sorted order"* yes, it is @variable , but that sort order is useless if it doesn't match what you're looking for. If I asked you to give me a list of everyone who has the first name "Aaron" from the phone book, could you do that easily? The phone book is sorted, just like your index.

Comment: If I am looking for name Aaron and the name column is sorted then yes it can be done easily with index seek. What are you trying to say?

Comment: How does a list of people sorted by surname, help you find people who's first name is Aaron...? (hint: It doesn't)

Comment: Where have you said that it was sorted by LastName? Anyways, my question is referring to just one field (where clause) and it is indexed (sorted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never see SQL Server choose a scan for this query if you have an index on `StockItemID` as this covers the query and there is no "tipping point" issue.

It will *always* choose a seek even if it estimates that 100% of the rows match.

### Example

```
CREATE TABLE OrderLines
(
OrderID     INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
StockItemID INT INDEX IX1
);

INSERT INTO OrderLines
            (StockItemID)
SELECT 1
FROM   sys.all_objects

SELECT StockItemID
FROM   OrderLines
WHERE  StockItemID = 1;
```

[image]

In the case that the seek returns all the rows in the table the only difference between a seek and an index ordered scan is how the first row is located (by navigating the depth of the B tree or simply going to the first index page from metadata). This is likely to be negligible.

One edge case where a scan may perform better would be if an allocation ordered scan was preferable and you are running with a table lock or `nolock` so this becomes a viable option.

Comment: I am referring to a book "Exam Ref 70-762 Developing SQL Databases" which has this example and it reads on page number 338 as: "Because this (stale statistics) value is relatively low, the query optimizer generated a plan using an index seek, which could be less optimal than performing a scan when data volumes are high". I am trying to understand why a seek is considered expensive.

Comment: If the example in the book is exactly as your question then it is wrong. Try creating the table and updating the stats - you will see you still get a seek

Comment: @variable, time to get a new book. FWIW, I sometimes see questions on exams with answers that are incorrect or misleading.